# Is there a way to make an operator know if the context viewport is in ortho or perspective mode?

Tags: python, 3d-view

I would like my custom operator to have 2 behaviours :

- Case 1: Viewport is in perspective mode, do function 1.
- Case 2: Viewport is in orthogonal mode, do function 2.

How can I get that information with the Python API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, you can check [`is_perspective`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html?highlight=ortho#bpy.types.RegionView3D.is_perspective).

You can get the perspective of the current context (provided the current context is a 3D view) with `bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.is_perspective`.

For example, running this in the text editor will print `Perspective` or `Ortho` to the terminal for each 3D view.

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                if space.region_3d.is_perspective:
                    print("Perspective")
                else:
                    print("Ortho")
```

Comment: The link speaks about a type. I can't see how to get that info in context. I mean a full path like bpy.context. ... .RegionView3D.is_perspective

Comment: @matali `type` is only used for documentation. Try `bpy.context.region_data.is_perspective`

Comment: gives me eror : object has no item "is_perspective"

Comment: @matali Oops, I meant `space_data`. Will update answer.

Comment: problem is I need the state of the view where the operator is called, not for every view. So I really need a full path that gives me the context view perspective/ortho state.

Comment: For the current area's View3D perspective: `bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.is_perspective`. It also works for quadview (amazing!)

Comment: @matali Replace `region_data` with `space_data` in my above comment. The example in the answer is only intended as an example (since it's run from the text editor it will not have any 3D views in the current area context, so I decided to make it print for all 3D views in the current screen). As coDEmanX said, `bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.is_perspective` will work provided the current context is a 3D view.

Comment: @gandalf3 maybe update the answer with the full path. I made an operator, it works. CoDEmanX Thanks for the path :) But for the quadview, it returns me the value of the upper right window only even if called from an ortho view... are you sure it works for all 4 quad views ?

Comment: The upper right view in quadview mode is supposed to be navigated, that other 3 shouldn't be changed (but can). I don't think you can test the other 3, 'cause we are apparantly lacking access to the data with python: https://developer.blender.org/T39028